# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ax - x^2/2}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ax - x^2/2}dx$

I tried to do this:

$(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$$e^{ax - x^2/2}dx)^2$ = $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$$e^{a(x+y) - (x^2 + y^2)/2}dxdy$ = $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}$$e^{r(\sin\theta + \cos\theta) - r^2/2}rdrd\theta$

I do not know how to proceed

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you should complete the square: $e^{ax-\frac{x^2}{2}}=e^{\frac{a^2-(x-a)^2}{2}}=e^\frac{a^2}{2}e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, because I had already evaluated $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2/2}dx$

Comment: Complete the square, make an appropriate linear substitution, and use the value of the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can complete the square:

$$e^{ax-\frac{x^2}{2}}=e^\frac{a^2-(x-a)^2}{2}=e^\frac{a^2}{2}e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}}$$

This will reduce your integral to:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$$